# Why does 1bpp PNG image file size increase when the colors are inverted?

Tags: image, compression, png

When I generate black-and-white png images with 1 bit per pixel indexed color, it seems to make a noticeable difference in the file size if if I choose to use black background over white one. The attached images should have exactly the same information, and both are created by .NET 4's Bitmap.Save() function.

Why is the image with white background significantly larger when compressed?

Black background: 4.62KB
[Black background 4.62KB](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t8v2ovhobgkgtph/output.png?dl=0)

White background: 5.67KB
[White background: 5.67KB](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ymszu5g2y9r6a2s/output2.png?dl=0)

Comment: Would be interesting to see these PNGs optimized by ScriptPNG or some other very thorough optimizer.

Comment: @usr: actually, in this case not *that* interesting. These optimizers test all possible row filters for the smallest possible result. But here it is fortunate the images have *no* row filters, and so the difference can directly be attributed to the compression algorithm itself.

Comment: @Jongware true, but these optimizers also try hard to create a small compression result. They have understanding of the deflate format. I'd expect any difference to vanish because the DEFLATE algorithm does not differentiate between specific byte values as far as I know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is perhaps surprising, but quite simple, and lies in the PNG format itself.

As already mentioned, PNG applies a filter to each line. This helps compression for images which have a pattern within a line or between neighbouring lines. In this case, the image is pretty much single color with just a few dots sprinkled in, so using no filter yields the best result.

The [filter byte is stored as the first byte](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#7Filtering) of each image line. This is key.

> The filter step itself results in a sequence of bytes of the same size as the incoming sequence, but in a different representation, **preceded by a filter type byte**. [...] The filter type byte is not considered part of the image data, but it is included in the datastream sent to the compression step.

With no filter used, the filter byte is `0x00`. Example of a black 1-bit 4x4 image, with filter bytes bolded.

**`0`**`0 0 0 0`
**`0`**`0 0 0 0`
**`0`**`0 0 0 0`
**`0`**`0 0 0 0`

The same image as a flat sequence, as received by the compressor.

**`0`**`0 0 0 0`**`0`**`0 0 0 0`**`0`**`0 0 0 0`**`0`**`0 0 0 0`

And the image with pixels inverted.

**`0`**`1 1 1 1`**`0`**`1 1 1 1`**`0`**`1 1 1 1`**`0`**`1 1 1 1`

It's obvious which compresses better.

In the white background image provided, streams of `0x01` are regularly interrupted by a `0x00` filter byte, with a negative effect on compressibility. In the black background image, there is no such effect.

Comment: Good find. You should also mention that his images would be the same size if the palette reflected the color change instead of the image data.